# Custom Extension Method in Linq-EF Equivalent to SQL "IN" Clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to create a custom Linq to Entities extension method which takes a comma-delimited string, converts it to an array, then using `IEnumerable<string>.Contains` to generate the equivalent of a SQL IN clause.

Easy enough when you always know the table/entity and its column/property that you want to apply this filter to. The challenge is that I want to be able to use this extension method on any entity or property.

This is how far I've come:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> CustomInClause<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> myQuery, Expression<Func<TSource, string>> colExpression, string filterCriteria)
{
    string[] myArray = filterCriteria.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    //Various other operations here..............

    if (myArray.Length > 0)
    {
        myQuery = myQuery.Where(b => myArray.Contains(colExpression));
    }

    return myQuery;
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to use colExpression as a dynamic expression which will be the equivalent of `x => x.SomeColumn` where SomeColumn could be any string/varchar column.

I would then implement this extension like this:

```
var q = context.SomeTable.CustomInClause(f => f.SomeColumn, someString);

var q2 = context.OtherTable.CustomInCluse(f => f.OtherColumn, otherString);
```

Right now I get this error:

> 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best
>   extension method overload
>   'ParallelEnumerable.Contains>>(ParallelQuery>>,
>   Expression>)' requires a receiver of type
>   'ParallelQuery>>'

I'm not quite sure how to use a parallel query in this instance, or if there is another solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build `Contains` call as part of expression in where clause

```
var myArray = filterCriteria.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .ToList();   
var containsExp = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(myArray), 
                                    "Contains", null, colExpression.Body);

if (myArray.Count > 0)
{
    myQuery = myQuery.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>
                                        (containsExp, colExpression.Parameters));
}

return myQuery;
```

List is better than Array in this case, because list has `Contains` function and Array has only extension